# chart.js chart distorted with fixed width

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

I have a chart.js canvas inside a container which I gave a fixed min-width, so people could scroll the chart on mobile devices.

But as soon as the container has its fixed width, the chart is getting more distorted, the smaller the screen gets.

In the chart I have already tried setting the options `responsive: true` and `maintainAspectRatio: false`. This solved the problem a bit, but the chart is still distorted.

Chart.js Options:

```
var options = {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        stacked: false,
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          color: "rgba(151,151,151,0.2)"
        }
      }],
      xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          color: "rgba(151,151,151,0.2)"
        }
      }]
    }
  };
```

HTML:

```
<div class="tds-chart-inner tds-hor-scroll">
 <canvas id="tds-chart-mem"></canvas>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.tds-chart-inner {
 min-width: 850px !important;
}

.tds-hor-scroll {
 left: 0px;
 width: 100% !important;
 overflow-x: scroll;
}

canvas {
  left: 0px;
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

[image: working chart]
*Working chart*

[image: distorted chart]
*Distorted chart*

Comment: Try wrapping the chart in a div and setting that div to have a fixed size using css. I think that's how I fixed this issue in the past, but can't verify atm.

Comment: can you please share your code.

Comment: @Alex thats what I'm already doing :/

Comment: @ArpitJain I've added the code

Comment: To anyone: First try a browser restart or clearing all caches. While integrating ChartJS into a new project, I was experiencing the same kind of distortion but specifically for labels (titles, legend, etc). Ignored it, and then later in the day the browser crashed for other reasons, and coming back to the tab with ChartJS, distortion was gone.

Answer (score 4):

for me the problem was that graph was setting for itself height that was bigger that I myself had set to canvas.

my solution was:

1. I removed all height setups for canvas (css and tag attribute)
2. Created container tag for the canvas and set height to it
3. in chart options added:

```html
      responsive: true,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
```

**in the example in the question problem was in css:**

```css
canvas {
  left: 0px;
  height: 300px !important;
}
```

i would change it to:

```css
.tds-hor-scroll {
 overflow-x: auto;
}
.tds-chart-inner {
  min-width: 850px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tds-hor-scroll">
 <div class="tds-chart-inner">
   <canvas id="tds-chart-mem"></canvas>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport" />

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />


</head>

<style>
 .tds-chart-inner {
  width:100%;
 }


</style>

<body class="">

<div class="tds-chart-inner tds-hor-scroll">
 <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"> 
</script>


<script>
 var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
 var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
 type: 'line',
 data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3,80],
        backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
        ],
        borderColor: [
            'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
        ],
        borderWidth: 1
    }]
},
options: {
    scales: {
        yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
                beginAtZero:true,
                fontColor: 'red'
            }
        }]
    }
}
});



</script>
```

Comment: you want fixed width of the chart.

Comment: Yes, I want the width of the chart to be either 100%, or if the device width is smaller than 850px, i want the chart to keep the width of 850px... look at my code above

Comment: Do you have any further ideas?